# Change the Parent of a Git Branch to another Branch

Tags: git

I have a Dev Branch, QA and UAT branch. I have a branch 'X' created from Dev Branch. Dev is where all the developers are pushing their code. In UAT the code is much stable and less buggy. Can i change the parent of branch 'X' to UAT without any problems ?

Comment: If you made the X branch from Dev, then you can't turn back time and instead make it from UAT. You can either delete and recreate it OR  you can make X change its upstream branch so it will merge from/to UAT with the command ```set-upstream-to```

Comment: A question like this has probably been asked on Stack Overflow already, someone will need to mark this as a duplicate sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [git rebase command](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Your question is not very detailed, but you probably want something like

```
git rebase --onto UAT DEV X
```

As to whether that will work without any problems, this depends on how different the DEV and UAT branches are... you might have to resolve some merge conflicts manually if the two branches have diverged.